# Mapbox GL JS: Get point index in a MultiPoint geometry

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a `geojson.MultiPoint` which I'm displaying in a Mapbox map:

```
let geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [...]]},
        "properties": {"status": "status"}
    }]
}
```

Then I add a geojson source and a circle layer:

```
    map.addSource("gps-points", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: geojson,
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: "gps-points",
        type: "circle",
        source: "gps-points",
        paint: {
            "circle-radius": 3,
            "circle-color": "#1f77b4",
        }
    });
```

What I would like to do now is to get the index of the point I clicked in the click handler, something like:

```
map.on("click", "gps-points", function(e) {
    // get the index of this point in the coordinates array
});
```

I know I can do this easily by using `Point` instead of `MultiPoint`, but I have to visualize a very large number of points, and `Point` is not that scalable. Is it possible to do this in Mapbox GL JS using `MultiPoint`?

Comment: I suspect this kind of thing would be dependent on https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/issues/93